# mediaelement.js: 2.9.4 Not working as expected

Tags: mediaelement.js

I started using mediaelement.js last night (9/24/12) before the 2.9.4 update. I figured out how to use it as I wanted and set up a test page that worked great. Then I noticed the update, downloaded and installed on my test page (without backing up 2.9.3 unfortunately). Now when I test the flash fallback for an mp4 file in firefox, the flash player shows up but does not play and when I right click on it says "Movie not loaded..." In 2.9.3 it popped up right away and played the video just fine. I thought this may have to do with the new flashStreamer option but there is no documentation on how to USE said option yet. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh and the "MediaElementPlayer - Default" demo has the same problem. If you look at the single mp4 example. I have added the mime types to my server's config file. I have allowed the folders in my flash security settings. Essentially it's the same code, same environment, but in 2.9.3 it worked and 2.9.4 it didn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.